# What does "logical quantity" mean?

Tags: java, boolean, jls

In paragraph 4.2.5 of the Java Langage Specification 17, there is this sentence : "The boolean type represents a **logical quantity** with two possible values, indicated by the literals true and false (§3.10.3)". What does "logical quantity" mean? How can a quantity be logical? It doesn't make sense to me. I also searched through the internet to see any other context where this association of words is used and I didn't find anyting relevant...

Comment: A logical quantity is a value that is not a numeric measurement or count.

Comment: Well, perhaps I'm overthinking it. But maybe "value" instead of "quantity" would have been more appropriate here, since a quantity is by [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quantity) a measurable amount or number..

Comment: It is not. Note that your own link says "especially that can be measured", not "exclusively". There are quantities that cannot be measured. You cannot measure emotions, for example, but you can definitely say that you love/hate X more/less than Y. So that is something that can be quantified but not measured.